# Undefined reference to vtable SFML Android

Tags: c++, android-ndk, sfml

I am compiling a program that uses SFML on android. It compiles normally when I compile it with g++. When I run ndk-build in the android project directory I get the following error:

```
/home/engineer/Desktop/android_ndk/android-ndk-r11c/toolchains/arm-    linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: the vtable symbol may be undefined because the class is missing its key function (see go/missingkeymethod)
/home/engineer/Desktop/android/jni/SandJar.hpp:16: error: undefined reference to 'vtable for SandJar'
```

I have an abstract class jar and 2 class sandyJar and sandjar that both inherit it. However, I don't understand why it compiles for g++ but doesnt for the ndk-build command.
Here are some of the source files stripped down(it compiles from main):

Main.cpp:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode::getDesktopMode(), "");

    int WIDTH = window.getSize().x;
    int HEIGHT = window.getSize().y;

    vector<Jar*> jars;

    SandJar SJAR(5,5,5,WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    CandyJar CJAR(5,5,5,WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    CJAR.add();
    CJAR.move(120, 0);

    jars.push_back(&CJAR);
    jars.push_back(&SJAR);
    etc.
}
```

Jar.hpp

```
class Jar 
{
    public:

        virtual void add() = 0;
        virtual void draw(sf::RenderWindow&) = 0;
        virtual void update() = 0;
        virtual void move(int,int) = 0;
        virtual void setScale(float) = 0;
        virtual void incAnim() = 0;
        virtual void decAnim() = 0;

};
```

SandJar.hpp

```
class SandJar : public Jar
{

public:
  //initializer
  SandJar(const int, const int, const int, const int, const int);
  SandJar(const int);
  //function for adding candy
  void add();
  void update();
  void draw(sf::RenderWindow&);

  void incAnim();
  void decAnim();
  void move(int, int);
  void setScale(float);

private:
 //vars
};
```

SandJar.cpp

```
SandJar::SandJar(int Capacity){

}

SandJar::SandJar(int Width, int Height, int Capacity, int WindowW, int WindowH){

}

void SandJar::init() {

}

void SandJar::incAnim() {

}

void SandJar::decAnim() {

}

void SandJar::move(int x, int y)
{

}

void SandJar::setScale(float scl)
{
}

void SandJar::update() {

}

void SandJar::add() {

}

void SandJar::draw(sf::RenderWindow& window) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out there was no problem with any of the code. The problem was the Android.mk file used for the project. I appended the hpp and cpp files to LOCAL_SRC_FILES and it built correctly. It says not to include "includes" in LOCAL_SRC_FILES but once added it compiled correctly. There may be a better fix.